# How to find nscanned in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to use explain() in mongoose. What is the equivalent statement in mongoose for db.collection.find().explain() (this works in mongodb terminal)? I couldn't find the answers in the doc

Answer (score 5):

Not directly.  However, what you can do is enable Mongoose's debug logging so that you can see the actual query it's using and then copy it into a MongoDB shell and run `explain()` on it.

To enable Mongoose's debug logging to the console, add the following to your code:

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);
```