# Search suggestions: Insanely slow Mongo retrieval time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, search, amazon-ec2, mlab

I'm trying to implement real-time search suggestions on an input field. Retrieval time takes an average of 1500ms, and occasionally 3000ms+ for a collection of 23 documents.

This is running on MongoLab's Sandbox tier with "variable" RAM; AWS EC2 T2.Medium.

The relevant field of the data model is indexed (using Mongoose). Here's my query for retrieval.

```
model_user.find(
    { 'profile.local.displayName' : new RegExp( '^' + req.query.input, 'i') }
  , { 'profile.local.displayName' : 1, 'profile.local.photo' : 1 }) // photo is a url string
.limit(6)
.lean()
.exec(function (err, data) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  next(data);
}); // end exec
```

Is this normal for Mongo? Should I not be using `.find()` cursor for realtime search suggestions? If so, what else should I use instead?

*Edit (8:52pm PT): Just upgraded to shared multi-node replica set on MongoLab. No change in query speed.*

*Edit (9:13pm PT): Correction for the previous edit, new speed is 550ms-650ms on the multi-node cluster*

*Edit (9:56pm PT): @jsh I'm not too familiar with .explain() and the console is telling me that it's not a function. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506002/how-to-find-nscanned-in-mongoose) turning on Mongoose debugger is equivalent, so here's the output (unformatted from the direct copy).*

```
Mongoose: users.find({ 'profile.local.displayName': /^Daniel/i }) { limit: 6, fields: { 'profile.local.displayName': 1, 'profile.local.photo': 1 } }  
GET   [A] /api/search/username?input=Daniel           200 3.317s
```

Comment: Your query seems correct and should not be that slow. Probably some other factors causing the slowness.

Comment: What's the expected speed? Ballpark number would be helpful

Comment: My application with 200+ documents and a relatively more complicated structure takes around 20ms RTT from the browser to the database back to the browser. Everything is hosted on the local network though.

Comment: Can you please post the explain()? Also, I use a search tool for what you are doing. Lucene, or Elastic Search, are tools built for what you are trying to do. Use MongoDB to store your data and a search tool with an index built for retrieving data the way you like. Here is another post on this subject you might find useful that suggest using RegEx can be slow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13034140/mongodb-simple-prefix-query-with-regex-and-sort-is-slow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've updated the question with the output of `explain()`. What's the speed like on Lucene and Elastic Search?